# How do I get back data from a database using express.js without the result being undefined

Tags: sql, node.js, reactjs, database, express

`I've been trying to display a database product with react but none of my approaches seem to work.

This is my node.js/express code :

```
const express = require('express');
const database = require('./config/database');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');

const PORT = 3001;
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get('/products/:productId', (req, res) => {
  console.log('request recieved');
  const productId = req.params.productId;
  const query = `SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id = ${productId}`;

  database.query(query, (err, result) => {
      if (err) console.log(err);
      console.log(result);
      res.send(result);
  });
});

app.listen(PORT, 'localhost');
```

I tried to fetch and log it with axios but the results are undefined :

```
const productId = params.productId;
const url = `/product/${productId}`;

const [{data, loading, error}] = useAxios(url);
console.log(data);

I also tried the regular approach : 

  const fetchProduct = async (url) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(url);
      console.log(response);
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log(data);
    } catch(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    return data;
  }

  const product = fetchProduct(url);
  console.log(product);`
```

Some help would be appreciated

Comment: const `url = \`/product/${productId}\`;` should be `const url = \`/products/${productId}\`;` right? Maybe a typo?

Comment: Check that `productId` in your express app is defined, and what is returned from the logs after the db call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you create an arrow-function that it returns a Promise

```js
const getById = (productId) => {
    const query = `SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id = ${productId}`;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        database.query(query, (err, result)=> {
            err ? reject(err): resolve(result)
        })
    })
}
```

as our `getById` arrow-function returns a promise we need to `async/await` on it, so the `app.get` will be like this

```js
app.get('/products/:productId', async(req, res) => {
    console.log('request recieved');
    const productId = req.params.productId;
    const product = await getById(productId)
    res.status(200).send(product)
});
```

One more thing, in your code you wrote

`app.use(express.json());`

and

`app.use(bodyParser.json());`

those two instruction do the SAME THING, so you need to delete one of them, and it better be the `bodyParser` one, because the body-parser is just deprecated and you don't need to install it, you just need to add

`app.use(express.json())`

`app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))`